Linear regression on categorical variable, how to interpret the F-statistic?
I am using statsmodels to fit a regression:
smf.ols(formula=change ~ C(location))`

where change is a continuous variable.
I have a lot of locations and some of the p-values for the individual coefficients are statistically significant.
Nevertheless, the p-value of the F-statistic is not.
Is it correct to report that p-value as the significance of the location on the change?
Thank you!

That depends on what are your research questions and goals. But if you are interested in pairwise comparisons between locations, you can report them even in the absence of a significant omnibus effect.

I am trying to show that the location doesn't have a significant effect on change. My understanding is that coefficient p-values are only a comparison to the reference. So is the F-statistic answering my question?

Yes, the coefficients and p-values in the omnibus regression output are the comparisons between your reference location and other locations. It's customary to also extract other comparisons. E.g. say you had 4 levels of location and number 1 would be the reference. The regression output would give you comparisons 1-2, 1-3 and 1-4. Then, typically you would extract other comparisons too (i.e. 2-3, 2-4 and 3-4).
The omnibus F and these pairwise comparisons are not always in agreement. Some of the pairwise comparisons can be significant even when F-test is non-significant (see Do we need a global test before post hoc tests? and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5925602/
Your question is a bit tricky to answer because typically people are more interested in the post-hoc comparisons and want to know whether they can do them if the overall F is non-significant, to which the answer is yes. However, if you are not interested in pairwise comparisons and the overall F is non-significant then...I'm not sure? I guess I would check all pairwise comparisons with p-value correction and see if any remain significant (the omnibus output may not apply p-value correction, so you may want to do this manually). If there are significant pairwise comparisons after p-value adjustment, you need to decide if they are large enough to cause problems to saying there are no location effects on change.
